# Angular Form issue

Tags: angularjs

I have a form which contains two div which should be displayed as per form submission value but as soon as I put in that logic, I am loosing the binded angular ng-model variables and it is getting refreshed. How can I resolve that? Below is the html page

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div class="container full-body" ng-controller="myCtrl" >

            <div class="row header-page">

                    <div class="col-md-4 happy-face-header" ><img src="img/mad-lib-happy-face-2.png"/></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6  happy-face-logo">
                        <img src="img/ng-mad-libs-logo-2.png"/>
                        <h2 style="text-align:center">Automate This!</h2>
                    </div>

            </div>

            <form name="madlibform" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
                <div class="madlibwordschoose"  ng-if="!madlibform.$submitted">
                <div class="row wordstochoose">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h1 style="text-align: left; margin-left: -10px;">Provide the following words</h1>
                            </div>

                            <div class="'col-md-12">
                                Choose a gender for this madlib game
                                <select name="gender" ng-model="gender">
                                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" name="female_name" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder='female/male name' ng-model="female_name"  required ng-minlength="2"/> <div class="col-md-1"><span class="error" ng-if="madlibform.$submitted && madlibform.female_name.$error.required">
    A name is required!
</span></div>
                            <input type="text" name="dirty_task" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Dirty task" ng-model="dirty_task"/><div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <input type="text" name="obnoxious_celebrity" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Obnoxious celebrity" ng-model="obnoxious_celebrity"/><div class="col-md-1"></div>

                    </div>
                <div class="row wordstochoose">
                            <input type="text" name="job_title" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Job title" ng-model="job_title"/><div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <input type="text" name="celebrity" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Celebrity" ng-model="celebrity"/><div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <input type="text" name="huge_number" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Huge number" ng-model="huge_number"/><div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="row wordstochoose">
                            <input type="text" name="tedious_task" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Tedious task" ng-model="tedious_task"/><div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <input type="text" name="useless_skill" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Useless skill" ng-model="useless_skill"/><div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <input type="text" name="adjective" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Adjective" ng-model="adjective"/><div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    </div>
                <input style="text-align: right" type="submit"  value="Generate My Madlib" />
                </div>

                <div ng-show="madlibform.$submitted">
                <div  class="row fillthewords">
                        <p><a ng-show="female_name === undefined || female_name ===''">[female/male name]</a>{{female_name}} was a <a ng-show="job_title === undefined || job_title ===''">[job title]</a>{{job_title}} who loved technology. Although <a ng-show="gender==='male'">he</a><a ng-show="gender==='female'">she</a>  loved parts of <a ng-show="gender==='male'">his</a><a ng-show="gender==='female'">her</a> job, <a ng-show="gender==='male'">he</a><a ng-show="gender==='female'">she</a> absolutely hated<a ng-show="tedious_task === undefined || tedious_task ===''">[tedious task]</a>  {{tedious_task}} and <a ng-show="dirty_task === undefined || dirty_task ===''">[dirty task]</a>{{dirty_task}}.
                            So,<a ng-show="female_name === undefined || female_name ===''">[female name]</a> {{female_name}} met with <span ng-show="gender==='male'">his</span><a ng-show="gender==='female'">her</a> life mentor <a ng-show="celebrity === undefined || celebrity ===''">[Celebrity]</a>{{celebrity}} who told <a ng-show="gender==='male'">his</a><a ng-show="gender==='female'">her</a> to learn how to <a ng-show="useless_skill === undefined || useless_skill ===''">[useless skill]</a>{{useless_skill}} with Thinkful. Thinkful didn't offer a course on <a ng-show="useless_skill === undefined || useless_skill ===''">[useless skill]</a>{{useless_skill}} so <a ng-show="gender==='male'">he</a><a ng-show="gender==='female'">she</a> studied programming instead.
                            What a great decision! With <a ng-show="gender==='male'">his</a><a ng-show="gender==='female'">her</a> new skills, <a ng-show="female_name === undefined || female_name ===''">[female/male name]</a>{{female_name}} built a(n) <a ng-show="adjective === undefined || adjective ===''">[adjective]</a>{{adjective}} robot named <a ng-show="obnoxious_celebrity === undefined || obnoxious_celebrity ===''">[obnoxious celebrity]</a>{{obnoxious_celebrity}} that not only loved <a ng-show="dirty_task === undefined || dirty_task ===''">[dirty task]</a>{{dirty_task}} but did it <a ng-show="huge_number === undefined || huge_number ===''">[huge number]</a>{{huge_number}} faster. </p>
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Start Over" ng-click="resetfunc()"/>
                </div>
            </form>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Below is the script for controller in angular

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngMessages'])
.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.gender='female';
    $scope.reset=true;


    $scope.submit=function()
    {
      console.log($scope.female_name);
      $scope.madlibform.$submitted=true;
      $scope.reset=false;
      console.log($scope.female_name);

    };
    $scope.resetfunc=function(){
       $scope.madlibform.$submitted=false;
       $scope.reset=true;
   };


}]);
```

Comment: have you tried ng-form, or please provide a plunkr to better understand your situation.

Comment: I have not tried ng-form . I have this code in my github project url : https://github.com/inarayan/AngularAssignmentMadlibs/tree/userstory-add-a-form

Comment: I tried to create pen, I think you missing a closing tag somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'll update if you get a pen/plunker together.
I think all you need to add is required to the required inputs:

```
// or variation of ng-required="expression"
<input type="text" required name="tedious_task" class="col-md-3 words-block" placeholder="Tedious task" ng-model="tedious_task" />
```

Also validate the form with using:

```
<input style="text-align: right" type="submit"  value="Generate My Madlib" ng-disabled="madlibform.$invalid" />
```

Comment: I have figured out the problem and the problem was with me using ng-if instead of ng-show ..although I have not been able to figure out why it is different for ng-show and ng-if

Comment: @indra ng-show still allows the DOM to construct those elements and shows them conditionally, and ng-if will thrash thoose elements conditionally will just add a comment as a reference to that line should it validate truthy.

Comment: Thank you @alphapilgrim.this answer makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to replace ng-if with ng-show which somehow is related to scope visibility. I am still trying to figure out why it makes difference but yes the ng-show works for this problem statement.